# Scaling app / keyboard on iOS - react Native

Tags: react-native

I just trying to disable scaling my application.

I wrote it in react-native version 0.42.3. All things: fonts, icons and components. I want to prevent this "feature".

I just want to have more space on the bigger device but for now, it's something like that: I have 16px on an iPhone 5s but on iPhone 6 it becomes ~20px (or some other proportion)

Example (what I want):

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: This might be caused by the pixel ratio difference between devices. You can write a normalize function that can calculate the pixel ratio and sets the desired fontSize for your texts. If you are using flex then view sizes should not be a problem since flex can be proportional to device width and height.

Comment: Tnx for responding. Could you send me some link for tutorial/article about that?

Comment: There is a normalize function on [react-native-elements](https://github.com/react-native-training/react-native-elements/blob/master/src/helpers/normalizeText.js) but its not exactly what you looking for I think.

Comment: Even that - tnx :) I will try to do a similar thing.